# .NET MVC populate jquery datatable from JsonResult

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate a jQuery DataTable using the code below:

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var data = $('#giveUps').DataTable({
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/GiveUp/GiveUpView",
            "aoColumns": [
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "date-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "number-range" },
                { "type": "text" },
                { "type": "text" }
            ]
        });
    });
```

My controller:

```
    public ActionResult GiveUpView()
    {
        var result = GiveUpRepository.Instance.GetGiveUp();
        return Json(result.Take(10).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I checked in the chrome debug that the response is coming int the Json as bellow:

```
 [{"AId":"T-2-1471982820928-7","TInfo":382010,"Seg":1,"Mar":10,"Cod":"X","Nick":"BILL","Account":203627,"SecondNick":"XXX","Origin":203627,"Name":"Test","Up":"Yes","Quantity":300,"Price":12.87,"Number":"54360","GiveUpDateTime":"\/Date(1471982820000)\/","Status":"APPROVED","Desk":"","OffHours":1541,"ErrorDescription":"","Key":"T-2-1471982820928-7|382010"}]
```

But the datatable keeps showing **Processing...**.  Also, there is an HTML table with the `id="giveUps"` in the cshtml.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

```
I change the function for the following:
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = $('#giveUps').DataTable({
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "/GiveUp/GiveUpView",
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                { "mDataProp": "AId", "aTargets": [1] },
                { "mDataProp": "TInfo", "aTargets": [2] },
                { "mDataProp": "Seg", "aTargets": [3] },
                { "mDataProp": "Mart", "aTargets": [4] },
                { "mDataProp": "Cod", "aTargets": [5] },
                ...
                ]
            });
        });`
```

It's working fine but the time is not showing as dateTime but as string /Date(1471982820000)/ any sugestions?

Comment: Are you sure that no errors have occurred?  When the 'Processing...' message is displayed and never goes away, that is usually an indication that there is an error.  This could be a datatype issue.

Comment: Did you mean a jquery Datatable?

Comment: you may want to research what the json structure should be... you might need to add `return Json(new {aaData = result.Take(10).ToList()}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`; or something

Comment: David Tansey, i double checked there's no error and also i'm receiving the json, i can see it on the response in the network debug from chrome.

Comment: After done what JamieD77 said i'm getting the following error:
table id=giveUps - Requested unknow parameter '0' for row 0, column 0

Comment: I change the Controller to convert the item toJSon:
`List<string> json = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
               json.Add(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
            }`

But now i'm getting the first char of the json object and putting each one in a row.

Comment: Are you omitting something in your example of initialization? Could you double check that columns in your html markup matches the columns in the datatables config ?

Comment: Nope, i'm not omitting anything, double checked and the numbers are equal, there are empty values i don't know if this is a problem.